# Print defined content using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I used [the solution from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210317/how-to-print-a-div-using-a-javascript) but it also shows the URL on the document.
[image]

Comment: Please explain your problem better and give an example of the expected output and the output you get.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove header and footer in html to print page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849926/remove-header-and-footer-in-html-to-print-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to remove the URL within the HTML page. You'll need to change that in the printing settings of your browser - if your browser allows you to to.